# Error en consola: The value "" for key "width" is invalid, and has been ignored

Tags: javascript

Me está saliendo un error en consola; estoy haciendo un slider de una página, y no me muestra la imagen. Ya está tanto el html, el css y el js, pero me sale el error

> The value "" for key "width" is invalid, and has been ignored.

y no puedo encontrar dónde está el problema.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], recuerda realizar el [tour] y revisar [ask]. Debes poner el código con el que quieras que te ayudemos. Y es muy probable que dentro del error que te muestre, salga la línea de código donde estás haciendo esa asignacion. Edita tu pregunta y pon la información relevante para poderte ayudar

Comment: Recuerda colocar un [repro]: ¡no se puede ayudar _a ciegas_! Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.